# when I use templates to define a template parameter, there's an error"identifier is undefined"

Tags: c++, templates, undefined

I want to use template to define a parameter which can be used in an reference of array. But after the templates, there are errors:
`error:'N':undeclared identifier.`、 `error: identifier N is not defined.`、and error:`'void DoubleThresholdLink(float (&)[1],double,double)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'float [397782]' to 'float (&)[1]'`
Here's the code:

```
template <int N>

void DoubleThresholdLink( float (&input)[N], double lowThreshold, double highThreshold)

int main(void) {

    static float image_out[397782] = {};
    
    DoubleThresholdLink(image_out, 50, 150);
               }
```

Comment: That's not the error I get from that code: [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/98aYvd). Did you mean [this](https://godbolt.org/z/xGYErK)?

Comment: While the complete code is complex, I'm sorry that the code I provided is incomplete.  And thank you for your help. I've already known the solution to the problem. If I put the templates on the previous line of the function, the program can run correctly.(in my original code, the template is on the top and the function 'DoubleThresholdLink' is in the middle). Thank you again for your help.

Comment: You mean that you have a forward declaration at the top and the definition in the middle like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/KE1K1j)?

Comment: It's like this(https://godbolt.org/z/GWs1da). The first error.

Comment: And if I put template in the middle like this (https://godbolt.org/z/rMMTG6), the 'undefined' error disappeared.

Comment: Yes, you cant define a function template without `template`. Both the declaration and definition needs `template`. Does this resolve the issue? Should we close it as a typo?

Comment: OK. Thank you for your help.